# Thread pool with bounded queue

Tags: java, multithreading

I have seen the thread pool executor implementation and the rejected execution policies that it provides. However, I have a custom requirement - I want to have a call back mechanism where in I get notifications when the queue size limit is reached and say when the queue size reduces to say 80 % of the max allowed queue size.

```
public interface ISaturatedPoolObserver {
 void onSaturated(); // called when the blocking queue reaches the size limit
 void onUnsaturated(); // called when blocking queues size goes below the threshold.
}
```

I feel that this can be implemented by subclassing thread pool executor, but is there an already implemented version? I would be happy to add more details and my work so far as and when needed to provide clarity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want to have a call back mechanism where in I get notifications when the queue size limit is reached...

I wouldn't subclass the executor but I would subclass the `BlockingQueue` that is used by the executor. Something like the following should work.  There are race conditions in the code around the `checkUnsaturated()` if you remove an entry and someone puts one back in.  You might have to synchronize on the queue if these need to be perfect.  Also, I have no idea what methods the executor implementations use so you might not need to override some of these.

```
public class ObservableBlockingQueue<E> extends LinkedBlockingQueue<E> {
     private ISaturatedPoolObserver observer;
     private int capacity;
     public ObservableBlockingQueue(ISaturatedPoolObserver observer,
         int capacity) {
         super(capacity);
         this.observer = observer;
         this.capacity = capacity;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean offer(E o) {
        boolean offered = super.offer(o);
        if (!offered) {
            observer.onSaturated();
        }
        return offered;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean offer(E o, long timeout, TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException {
        boolean offered = super.offer(o, timeout, unit);
        if (!offered) {
            observer.onSaturated();
        }
        return offered;
    }
    @Override
    public E poll() {
        E e = super.poll();
        if (e != null) {
             checkUnsaturated();
        }
        return e;
    }
    @Override
    public E poll(long timeout, TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException {
        E e = super.poll(timeout, unit);
        if (e != null) {
             checkUnsaturated();
        }
        return e;
    }
    @Override
    public E take() throws InterruptedException {
        E e = super.take();
        checkUnsaturated();
        return e;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean remove(E e) throws InterruptedException {
        boolean removed = super.remove(e);
        if (removed) {
            checkUnsaturated();
        }
        return removed;
    }
    private void checkUnsaturated() {
        if (super.size() * 100 / capacity < UNSATURATED_PERCENTAGE) {
            observer.onUnsaturated();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for the answer; however, a small glitch with the solution is that the blocking queue's thread safety can be compromised if not implemented well. This is where ThreadPoolExecutors#beforeExecute and afterExecute can work but it might have its own shortcomings.

Comment: Yeah, agreed.  I mentioned that in my answer.  Depends a lot on how exact you need the callbacks.  It would be a lot easier to know which methods were used by the service.

Comment: The methods, poll(), offer(), remove(), take() along with isEmpty, size, remainingCapacity, drainTo are used; the former being the relevant one's. I have also based on the advice attempted a full fledged answer which should also take care of thread safety, any suggestions or feedback on that?

Comment: I guess it's a little rude to take 90% of my answer and tweak it and submit it as your own.  If you wanted to comment on it and say I missed the `drainTo` or whatever then fine but my answer got you to your solution.  Right?

Comment: You are right; and my answer just elaborates your answer and tries to cater to thread safety concern. I will edit it to mention that it is an extension of your answer. I will delete if you still find it rude, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

So here is the code that I have based on the answer above. The call to saturated and unSaturated needs to be invoked during sustained load on the worker queue of the thread pool and I believe the implementation achieves it by making use of non blocking algorithm.

Also, this implementation can be used for any implementation of blocking queue (also the original queue could be bounded or unbounded).

I am using guava's ForwardingBlockingQueue to write my decorator. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

import com.google.common.util.concurrent.ForwardingBlockingQueue;

/**
 * @version $Id$
 * @param <E> the type of elements held in this blocking queue.
 */
public class BoundObservableBlockingQueue<E> extends ForwardingBlockingQueue<E> {

    /** observer to receive callbacks. */
    private final ISaturatedQueueObserver queueBoundObserver;

    /** original blocking queue being decorated. */
    private final BlockingQueue<E> queueDelegate;

    /** user specified blocking queue bound capacity. */
    private final int boundCapacity;

    /** user specified blocking queue bound capacity. */
    private final int boundThreshold;

    /** flag to represent the saturated state of the queue. */
    private final AtomicBoolean isSaturated = new AtomicBoolean(false);

/**
     * 
     * @param pQueue {@link BlockingQueue
     * @param pQueueBoundObserver {@link ISaturatedQueueObserver}
     * @param pBoundCapacity saturation capacity for the bound queue.
     */
    public BoundObservableBlockingQueue(final BlockingQueue<E> pQueue,
            final ISaturatedQueueObserver pQueueBoundObserver, final int pBoundCapacity) {
        queueDelegate = pQueue;
        queueBoundObserver = pQueueBoundObserver;
        boundCapacity = pBoundCapacity;
        boundThreshold = (int) 0.8 * pBoundCapacity;
    }

    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    @Override
    public final boolean offer(final E e) {
        boolean isOffered = delegate().offer(e);
        checkSaturated();
        return isOffered;
    }

    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    @Override
    public final boolean offer(final E e, final long timeout, final TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException {
        boolean isOffered = delegate().offer(e, timeout, unit);
        checkSaturated();
        return isOffered;
    }

    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    @Override
    public final E remove() {
        E element = delegate().remove();
        checkUnsaturated();
        return element;
    }

    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    @Override
    public final E poll() {
        E element = delegate().poll();
        checkUnsaturated();
        return element;
    }

    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    @Override
    public final E poll(final long timeout, final TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException {
        E element = delegate().poll(timeout, unit);
        checkUnsaturated();
        return element;
    }

    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    @Override
    public final E take() throws InterruptedException {
        E element = delegate().take();
        checkUnsaturated();
        return element;
    }

    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    @Override
    public final boolean remove(final Object o) {
        boolean isRemoved = delegate().remove(o);
        checkUnsaturated();
        return isRemoved;
    }

    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    @Override
    protected final BlockingQueue<E> delegate() {
        return queueDelegate;
    }

    // thread pool uses this only during invocation of shutdown; in which cases call to unSaturated isn't needed because
    // the queue is no longer ready to accept any more records.
    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    @Override
    public final int drainTo(final Collection<? super E> c) {
        return delegate().drainTo(c);
    }

    private void checkUnsaturated() {
        if (delegate().size() < boundThreshold && isSaturated.get()) {
            if (isSaturated.compareAndSet(true, false)) {
                queueBoundObserver.onUnsaturated();
            }
        }
    }

    private void checkSaturated() {
        if ((delegate().size() >= boundCapacity) && !isSaturated.get()) {
            if (isSaturated.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
                queueBoundObserver.onSaturated();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This still suffers from the same race conditions as my answer @Scorpion. The race is around a removal from the delegate and then another thread putting back into the delegate before you can check its `size()`.

Comment: Also, you should not need to do the `isSaturated.get()` test when you are doing the `isSaturated.compareAndSet`.  The whole point is that you do the `compareAndSet` and only act on it if the value matches the first arg.  That's another race condition.

Comment: A forwarding... Implementation by guava is useful to decorate a certain class; it provides an implementation of all the method of the interface and uses the delegate to handle it, so your third comment is wrong. http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/ForwardingBlockingQueue.html

Comment: @Gray : Answer updated to explicitly acknowledge your answer. Also regarding your first comment, I fail to see it as a problem as the callbacks are expected to happen on a best effort basis; so it might not happen on capacity of x, but for a value of x+1. Such contracts are quite normal for concurrent structures, example ConcurrentHashMap#size() wherein the size returned by the structure might change due to a concurrent add or remove. Thanks for your time and suggestions.