# Thread Pool Executor Monitoring Requirement

Tags: java, multithreading, monitoring, executorservice

In our production environments, we are using Thread Pool Executor to execute runntable task.  I need to develop a Thread pool Heartbeat a monitoring system for Thread pool Executor Service:

Every 60 seconds, the requirement is to collect following statistic about the Thread Pooled Executor:

1) size of the thread pool

2) length of queue waiting  for a thread  (a duration or  time task waited in  blocking queue before thread executed )

3) Average wait time in queue during the last heartbeat interval

4) Current active thread

5) Current non active threads.

I wanted to know is there any existing framework or Thread pool Executor Service which will provide above reporting requirements.

Thanks,

BMis13

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Spring?  If I'm not mistaken Spring's implementation of ThreadPoolExecutor supports JMX.

Comment: HI Dmitry,  Thanks for the reply !! I am not using Spring !  Plain old Java Core Program with Pooled Executor Service.

Comment: what are you using for monitoring? JMX?

Comment: We are using OLAP type offline system ( this will be deployed to 10,000 servers not just one JVM).   This is for big eCommerce website.  This for offline statistic gathering.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650464/thread-pool-with-bounded-queue (this post seems to give more idea)